# Does parents' family name refer to mother's married name or maiden name on VWP/ESTA form?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

The updated visa waiver form asks for my parents' "family" name, as shown below. Does this mean my mothers birth family name or her married family name?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts: That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @pnuts: But yours is different from the others, and you appear to have an authoritative source to cite.

Comment: @pnuts: heh... I looked at the `?` for that field, and didn't find any useful information. I guess you dug deeper. I still think your info would make for a good answer. I'd +1 it :)

Answer (score 12):

It's always the **current** name, since this is what she's **legally** known as. Any records - criminal, legal, etc that they might want to look up - or to check your back story, that's how they'd find her.

If they want the maiden name, they'll specifically ask for that.

Answer (score 9):

If she is married to your father and took his family name then as @pnuts said it's an convention to write this family name if it is not the case then I can't help you sorry.

The guidance about [Parents](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e2s1) is not specific on this point:

> Enter the names of your parents. These are required to complete the application. If you do not know the name of one or both of your parents, enter UNKNOWN, for each parent. This field can include the names of your biological, adoptive, step-parent or guardian.
>
> In the Family Name field, enter your parent's family name. The family name is required to complete the application. If you do not know one or both of your parents, enter UNKNOWN.
>
> In the First (Given) Name field, enter your parent's first (given) name. Do not include the middle name in this field. The first name is required to complete the application. If your parent has no first name, or if you do not know one or both of your parents, enter UNKNOWN.

There is though some guidance regarding 'family name' for the applicant:

[image: TSE42034 example]

The most relevant portion (emphasis added):

> ### Applicant Name
>
> In the Family Name field, **enter your family name as the family name appears on your passport under the Family Name or Surname field**. The family name is required to complete the application.

This suggests that for your parents' names, you should enter their name as it appears on your passport, as well.

Comment: Do you mean, "enter their names as it appears on **their** passports"?

Answer (score 8):

It is the name *she goes by*.  If your mother has been known as Jane Smith for 50 years, the fact that she was born Jane Jones is not of interest to the visa people.

Of course, why her current name is of interest to them escapes me.

Comment: Several people, including @Lilienthal, have suggested I amend my answer to refer to a "legal name".  In common-law jurisdictions like the US and the UK, there is no such thing as "legal name".  If you choose to call yourself "Buzz Killington the Third", that is up to you.  Obviously, if you are expecting the visa people to follow up with your mother in any way, it may be helpful to use the name they have for her on their documents already.

Comment: Good to know (initial comment removed).

Answer (score 5):

For info I just had the same issue today. I emailed ESTA Support in the USA and they confirmed that the mothers' Family Name is indeed her **MARRIED NAME**.

Hope this helps.