# ESTA approved but incorrect order of parents' first names and surnames

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

My girlfriend has been approved for ESTA, but when looking at the parents section, she has put their first name and surnames in the wrong order. Is this worth reapplying over? As stated, the ESTA has been approved.

Comment: Related: [Why do they now ask for parent's names on the US ESTA application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57697/why-do-they-now-ask-for-parents-names-on-the-us-esta-application). When you arrive with a visa waiver it would be pretty much third-degree to go into the parents' names.